# Passing command line arguments to npm 'pre' script and script with multiple commands

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-scripts

Is there a way to pass command line arguments to an npm 'pre' script or to a script which runs multiple commands?

Assuming a simple script `mySexyScript.js` that just logs out the process.argv :

```
console.log(process.argv);
```

**This works**

With an npm script:

```
...
"scripts": {
    ....
    "sexyscript": "node mySexyScript.js"
    ....
}
...
```

running:

```
npm run sexyscript -- --foo=bar
```

the arguments are logged to the console as expected.

**'pre' script - This doesn't work**

With an npm script:

```
...
"scripts": {
    ....
    "presexyscript": "node mySexyScript.js"
    "sexyscript": "node mySuperSexyScript.js"
    ....
}
...
```

running:

```
npm run sexyscript -- --foo=bar
```

the arguments are not passed to mySexyScript and they are not logged

**Multiple commands - This also doesn't work**

With an npm script:

```
...
"scripts": {
    ....
    "sexyscript": "node mySexyScript.js && node mySuperSexyScript.js"
    ....
}
...
```

running:

```
npm run sexyscript -- --foo=bar
```

the arguments are not passed to mySexyScript and they are not logged

Answer (score 7):

There is no way to pass args in the way that you are describing.

Assuming a `package.json`:

```
...
"scripts": {
    ....
    "somescript": "node one.js && node two.js"
    ....
}
...
```

Running:

```
npm run somescript -- --foo=bar
```

basically just runs

```
node one.js && node two.js --foo=bar
```

on the default system shell (usually `bash` or `cmd.exe`).

`npm` doesn't actually know anything about shell operators (i.e. `&&`), so it can't pass args to both scripts.